# Difference between first! and first method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax

What is the difference between `User.first` and `User.first!` in Ruby on Rails?

I see the example in the Ruby Guide but there is no explanation between why it's different. As far as I know, `!` is used to represent that the method is changing the variable.

*`User` represents a table.

Comment: Hi jason328, I don't think `first!` exists. It does not make sense in the context of querying table anyway(if User represents a table).

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html Section 1.1.4

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I didn't know there was a `first!` finder method in ActiveRecord. Thanks to your question, now I know :-)

`first!` is the same as `first` except that it **raises ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound if no record is found.**

More details here : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-first-21

Comment: It's worth noting that its a common Ruby convention for a method ending with `!` (where there is a method with the same name but not ending in `!`) does something destructive/explosive/raises.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know either, it's a win-win I guess

Answer (score -2):

The ! is a bang character. In other methods like create!, it forces the creation to occur. It skips validations and other things you have set up.

Comment: That's not what `create!` does. `create!` creates an object just like `create` but calls `save!` instead of `save` so an exception is raised if the record is invalid. (`save` returns `false` and doesn't raise an exception if validation fails or any associated callbacks return `false`.)